# How to use `return()` as expression?

Tags: c++, return

`||` is less verbose and easier to type than `if (...)`, so I'd like a way to do the following (which happens a lot in my code):

```
int bar() {...; return successFlag;}
int foo() {
    bar() || return(...);  // return early on errors
    ...
}
```

Is it possible?

Or even better, is it possible to `return` back to `main` from `bar`, instead of chaining through `foo`?

Comment: You perhaps want to read about exceptions. And no, `return` is not an expression and you cannot use it like that.

Comment: u can;t use such syntax . for error see exceptions

Comment: For your "even better" question, exceptions are the way to go.

Comment: As the others have said, the concept of throwing exceptions was invented to do exactly what you're looking for. They should, however, be restrained to actually *exceptional* cases, mainly because the whole mechanism of throwing and catching them is slow.

Comment: (It's interesting, though, how everywhere else you're told "don't do premature optimization", but at the least mention of exceptions you hear "They're too slow".)

Comment: "Less verbose and easier to type" does not excuse writing unreadable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, no: `return` is a keyword, not an expression, so it cannot combined in that form. I think you are instinctively reading `||` literally as meaning "or" in the English language sense - obviously that's not what it means.

For the second part, you could - in theory - by using exceptions, but it is a strongly discouraged practice. Exceptions are intended for "exceptional circumstances", more specifically, error conditions from which the code cannot recover locally (in the context of the current function/method) and where the proper action has to be determined at a higher level.

Use of exceptions as a general flow control mechanism has two problems:

- *Performance*: C++ compilers are optimized for "non-exceptional" code paths (because that's what should be happening normally) and so exception handling mechanisms tend to be very slow. This is not from lack of code optimization, but from the need of the mechanism to have a zero or near-zero cost if there are no exceptions, even if the cost is for exceptions to take a lot of work to process.
- *code clarity/testability*: using exceptions for control flow makes code immensely hard to read and unit-test properly in isolation.

Comment: The OP didn't really describe the context of his code, but the comment in his code *does* say that `bar` returning false would signify an error, so it sounds to me that the OP's situation would qualify as an "error condition from which the code cannot recover locally".

Comment: Perhaps mention the early exit style of `if (!bar()) return ERROR;` that would be simple and clear in my opinion. You can (and I do) put the return on the next line for clarity.

Comment: @sepp2k, I see your point about the comment in the code; I didn't notice it. I agree, of course, that if you're really talking about recovering from errors then exceptions are an entirely appropriate mechanism.

Comment: @Will, I am personally in favor of the "early exit on error" pattern, when feasible. As you probably know, some people are very strongly opposed to it because they want to see only one exit path (one-and-only-one `return`, always at the end of the body). I'm good with that view as well, but such approach can lead to code that is extremely hard to read (usually deep if-nesting with sentinel values). It's a divisive topic.

Answer (score -2):

For the first part - NO. For the second: setjmp and longjmp. But take note that both of them subvert the usual C++ stack based destructor calls and probably don't mix well with exceptions.

Comment: I'd never recommend setjmp/longjmp.  It's maybe OK if a skilled programmer learns about it on his own, but it's way too complex and full of pit-falls for a novice.